# Passing a variable into a URL

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, function

I have a function that contains a variable that I have accessed from a database. 
I am trying to concatenate that variable with a URL in the way stated below.

```
PopupWindow=window.open('Http://' + svrname +'/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=' + ctl,'DatePicker',settings);
```

I am receiving an error when I try and compile my code.
Here is the function:

```
     Public Function getserverName() As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim readData As SqlDataReader
    Dim path As String
    path = ""

    connection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("getServer"))
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("select [Email_Notification_Date] from GlobalDB where [Email_Notification_Date]='Batman'", connection)
    readData = command.ExecuteReader
    While readData.Read()
        path = readData.Item("Email_Notification_Date")
    End While
    connection.Close()
    Return path
End Function
```

And here is where I am trying to call the function:

```
    function PopupPicker(ctl,w,h)
{
var PopupWindow = null;
var serverName = new getServername;
svrname = serverName.getServername;
    settings='width='+ w + ',height='+ h + ',location=no,directories=no, menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,dependent=no';
    PopupWindow=window.open('Http://' + svrname +'/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=' + ctl,'DatePicker',settings);
    PopupWindow.focus();
}
```

P.S. the function does return a value.

EDIT: sorry, forgot to say I am trying to call a VB function from javascript
This is the window I get from the error.

```
Unhandled exception at line 200, column 5 in http://localhost:50209/Admin/EmployeeAssets.aspx || 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'getServername' is undefined
```

EDIT: I added an argument to the function and now it is giving me 'Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.'

here is my revised code

```
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function getServerName(suffix As String) As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim readData As SqlDataReader
    Dim path As String
    path = ""

    connection = New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("getServer"))
    connection.Open()
    command = New SqlCommand("select [Email_Notification_Date] from GlobalDB where [Email_Notification_Date]='Batman'", connection)
    readData = command.ExecuteReader
    While readData.Read()
        path = readData.Item("Email_Notification_Date")
    End While
    connection.Close()
    Return ("http://") + path + suffix
End Function
```

I have edited the main file to include a string as the parameter.

```
PopupWindow=window.open(<%= (New getServerName).getserverName("/Quoteman/DatePicker.aspx?Ctl=") %> + ctl,'DatePicker',settings);
```

Comment: Are you calling VB.NET code from JavaScript?

Comment: yes, sorry. forgot to specify the language

Comment: Please specify the error and possibly post the log. Is it a compilation or runtime error?

Comment: The error is on this line. 'var serverName = new getServername;' and it is a runtime error when I click the datePicker.

Comment: I see you're trying my first suggestion, then you don't need to mark the function as WebMethod, and you can keep it `Shared`, and change the call like `<%= getServerName.getserverName("...") %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling server side (you're connecting to a database) code from client side, the esiest way is, write the server name to your javascript on server.

```
PopupWindow = window.open('Http://' + '<%= GetServerName.getserverName() %>' +'/Quoteman/...');
```

Another possible way is to use AJAX call. You can check this blog post: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

It's using C# on server side, but that's OK, you can mark your function like this:

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function getserverName() As String
```

Comment: When I try that it is saying that 'getserverName is a type and cannot be used as an expression'.

Comment: So you put this function in a class named getServername?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the App_Code folder.

Comment: Then try change `getserverName()` to `(New getServerName).getserverName()`

Comment: When i do that it says 'Expression expected'.

Comment: I have made changes to the original question to accommodate the changes made in the original project.

Comment: OK, I see your update. You're using my first suggested way, so no need to mark your function as WebMethod, but you can keep it `Shared`. I've changed my description, please check.

Comment: That fixed the error but now when it has been concatenated it is saying that it is expecting ')' within the 'http://'.

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript runtime error: '**getServername**' is undefined

The function is called **getserverName**, JavaScript is case sensitive, maybe thats all.

Comment: I have change the capitalization and it is still not working for me. But thank you for that. I would have missed it.

Comment: Is the PopupPicker a Javascript function?
 If yes then that might work > var serverName = getservername();

Comment: I have done that and it still is not working. Very good point though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like returning a string is from a server method is what you want in which case you can use **[PageMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_methods.aspx)** object:

You can enable it by declaring script manager and Set the **[EnablePageMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods.aspx)** attribute to **true**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
 EnablePageMethods="true" 
 EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server" />
```

the declare the function as [WebMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like so It **must** be SHARED:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function getserverName() As String

End Function
```

Then script:

```
<script>
    function test(){
        alert(PageMethods.getserverName());
    }
</script>
```

There is also a way to do it with with jQuery but I haven't done it that way but [Check it out](http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/calling-a-pagemethod-with-jquery/)

Soruce of this example can be found [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View7B75C93E-C8C9-4576-972B-2C3138DFC671.htm) but in C# syntax.

Hope that helps.